# Entry function not working for simple program

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have difficulty understanding why this very simple piece of code doesn't work. Basically it's supposed to print anything out you type. It runs without errors but when I type something into the entry widget and press the submit button it doesn't print anything out. I'm using Python 3.xx.

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def GET():
    typed = e.get()
    print(typed)

e = Entry(window)
e.pack()
b = Button(window, text = "Submit", command = GET())
b.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you do any research or debugging before asking this? This sort of problem has been asked about dozens of times.

Comment: @BryanOakley I did, I just didn't think the "()" would make a huge difference..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is set the command to `GET` instead of `GET()`. All you need to do is pass is the reference, not the full function invocation, because that then passes on the return value:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

def GET():
    typed = e.get()
    print(typed)

e = Entry(window)
e.pack()
b = Button(window, text = "Submit", command = GET) # GET not GET()
b.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Now, it will execute GET accordingly. The callback only needs the reference of the function, not a function invocation which will get the return value. This is None in this instance and makes the button do nothing.

Comment: You're right, could you specifiy what you mean with return value? I'm new to python

Comment: When you call a function, you can return a value to the callee. Basically, a function that does an operation, then returns a value. Since your function *has no return statement*, it's None. Here's a [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) link.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`b = Button(window, text = "Submit", command = GET())`

Note that by doing `command=GET()` you are calling the function `GET` and then passing its return value (`None` in this case) to the `command` argument.

Instead, you should be doing `command=GET`. This will pass the function `GET` to the `command` argument rather than its return value.